# C: Advantages of passing by parameter vs returning value?

Tags: c, pointers, methods

I recently started using C from a background in C++, and I always noticed that C based libraries used "pass-by-parameter" over return types.

What I mean by that is, consider this function.

```
int getSum(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}
```

which would by written as

```
void getSum(int* out, int a, int b){
    *out = a + b;
}
```

This is only an example, just making something up for clarification.

Is there any advantage at all when using the second method over the first method?

Comment: If I would use the second method, I would pass an `int *` and use `*out = a + b`. But for such simple case I personally wouldn't emulate pass by reference at all but rather just return the value. It's much clearer IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's really no advantage. It significantly reduces flexibility in invoking the function. For example, you can do:

```
if (getSum (a, b) < 20)
```

But with the second, you have to do this:

```
int q;
getSum (&q, a, b);
if (q < 20)
```

Which is not only more lines of code but it's harder to follow its logic.

Imagine what this code would look like with the second version:

```
if ((getSum(a, b) < getSum(c, d)) ||
    (getSum(a, c) < getSum(b, d))
```

Yuck.

The only possible advantage of the second function is that you are 100% sure that any caller knows the return type, since you can only call it with an `int *`. But that's really not an advantage at all.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will not answer your question as to which is better to use, but let's have a look at the instructions generated by gcc for both functions

```
second_function:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)     <--- 8 bytes
        movl    %esi, -12(%rbp)    <--- 4 bytes
        movl    %edx, -16(%rbp)    <--- 4 bytes
        movl    -12(%rbp), %edx    <---
        movl    -16(%rbp), %eax    <---
        addl    %eax, %edx         <---
        movq    -8(%rbp), %rax     <---
        movl    %edx, (%rax)       <---
        nop
        popq    %rbp
        ret

first_function:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)     <--- 4 bytes
        movl    %esi, -8(%rbp)     <--- 4 bytes
        movl    -4(%rbp), %edx     <---
        movl    -8(%rbp), %eax     <---
        addl    %edx, %eax         <---
        popq    %rbp
        ret
```

We can see there is a difference: in the second function, it first has to move the address of the *out* parameter into a register and then move the result of a + b, which resides into *%edx*, into the memory location of the *out* parameter, whereas in the first function, the value of a + b resides into the register *%eax*. However, the first function has one extra instruction that needs to be carried but not shown above: after the function ends, it has to move the value from the register into the variable, whereas after the other function  ends, It already contains it

Also, the second function requires 8 extra bytes of space for the pointer, occupying in total 16 bytes, whereas the first function only requires 8 bytes.

Which one to use? It's a matter of preference and it also depends on what you are trying to do. Always try to go for the method that is easiest to understand.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, it's not always the case, but C libraries can adopt the pattern you mentioned so they can return an error code and make that behaviour consistent across the entire API.

The problem is that some operations can fail (say, file not existing, malformed, invalid values, etc) and without the concept of exceptions there need to be some other way to report when something goes wrong.
Sometimes, it's possible to just return a NULL pointer instead of a reference to the expected output object. This is the approach taken by `malloc()`. Other times, you may need to just produce an integer as the output of an operation. In this case, you might use negative numbers to indicate an error - if a negative values cannot be a valid output. But, as you can probably guess, this doesn't scale well.

So, some libraries solve the problem by always returning an error code on the entire API. If the function needs to produce one or more outputs, those are passed via reference parameters.